# Using solr 7.7.2, Is it safe to manually delete tlog with rm -rf ./tlog command after commit?

Tags: solr, solrcloud, solr7

I am using *solr* 7.7.2.

Our *CDCR* is broken for some reason.. So the size of *tlog* is huge now... I don't care *CDCR* for now, and just want to clean all these *tlog* first. Otherwise disk space will become full.

Is it safe to manually delete by using `rm -rf ./tlog` after commit(simply doing commit was not able to clean *tlog* because of *CDCR* malfunction)?

Comment: I think you'll get a faster answer by taking the question to the `solr-user` mailing list, and then posting relevant answers here.

Comment: I got the answer, it is no harm to delete tlog once it is committed.